# Transition freezing Android device

Tags: codenameone

I have a problem here.This here freeze my Android phone while it works very well on the emulator, it is performed on a click on a Toolbar Command.

getContentPane().replace(getContentPane().getComponentAt(0), createAbout(), CommonTransitions.createCover(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, false, 100));

I think it is because of the Transition.
Any help?

Comment: CommonTransitions is basically used to create animation effect from one form to the other. What are you trying to do? Animate the Container .replace() ?

Comment: I followed part of this code to obtain that effect https://github.com/codenameone/RestaurantDemo/blob/master/src/com/mycompany/myapp/MainUI.java

Comment: I set the transition to CommonTransitions.createEmpty() and now it does not freeze my UI anymore,I just have to click on the UI to refresh the Container, if I do not click on the screen it does not refresh.I would like to refresh it without clicking on the UI.This happens just on Android phone, on the simulator everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do if you just want to animate replacement is:

```
getContentPane().replace(getContentPane().getComponentAt(0), createAbout(), null);

getContentPane().animateLayoutAndWait(200);
```

Comment: But I do not want to animate the replacement, I just not want to freeze my phone when I do getContentPane().replace().I just do not want to click TWICE on the UI when a new Container is fired.

Comment: I think I just solved the problem removing gradients that I understood are not well viewed by my mobile phone :P

Answer (score 0):

In the current implementation if you are running two animations at once (replace, layout etc.) you might create an invalid state that can trigger an exception/freeze.

If there is a chance of that you need to set a flag before starting the animation and release it when its done e.g.:

```
if(!globalLockFlag) {
    globalLockFlag = true;
    // change stuff and use animateLayoutAndWait or replaceAndWait
    globalLockFlag = false;
} else {
   // use timer or callSerially to postpone or skip animation entirely
}
```